# Which actions need to be performed on both ends for a TCP connection

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I don't quite understand exactly how a few of the features are shared when a `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` communicate.

Let's say the following code is run (for now ignore synchronisation):

Server:

```
Dim server As New TcpListener(localAddr, port)
server.Start()

Dim client As TcpClient = server.AcceptTcpClient()
```

Client:

```
Dim client As New TcpClient
client.Connect(hostAddr, port)
```

And the connection is successfully established. Now there are two `TcpClient` instances — one on server side and one on client side. However, they share the same network stream through `TcpClient.GetStream()`.

I'm slightly confused — does the client pass itself and all of its properties to the server when `server.AcceptTcpClient()` is called?

What about any changes to either of the `TcpClient` instances after this? When the connection shuts down I call this on both sides:

```
client.GetStream.Close()
client.Close()
```

But I get an exception with `TcpClient.GetStream.Close()` on the client which executes this code the latest because it tells me that the client is already closed (this happens when the above code isn't perfectly synchronised on both sides).

What about the `.SendBufferSize` and `.ReceiveBufferSize` properties? Do I need to set this on both sides of the connection?

Hope someone can clear up my confusion with an explanation of how exactly the `TcpClient/Listener` classes work during the communication — so far I haven't been able to find documentation explaining what exactly happens.

Comment: It is not the same `NetworkStream`. Each of the streams is bound to its `TcpClient`'s underlying `Socket`. -- The `Send/ReceiveBufferSize` properties are just indicating how _you expect_ to send or receive. There's not much use in changing them, and having different on client/server doesn't really affect anything either.

Comment: @VisualVincent Are the Send/Receive properties sent across in 'server.AcceptTcpClient()'? I don't quite understand what you mean by not much use... Surely if I were planning on exchanging large files, then I'd increase them?

Comment: Nothing is sent across. The only synchronized property is the `Connected` property. The `***BufferSize` properties are just an indication of how much you expect to send or receive every time you call `NetworkStream.Read/Write`. Quoting [**the documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.sendbuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx): _"The SendBufferSize property gets or sets the number of bytes that you are expecting to send in each call to the NetworkStream.Write method."_

Comment: An entire file shouldn't be sent in a single `Write()` call, but should be split up into packets. The `BufferSize` properties only control the network buffer. Say you have a buffer of 8192 and you send data of 9192 bytes. That would require the `NetworkStream` to send first 8192 bytes and then the additional 1000 bytes. In general, changing these properties are not necessary.

Comment: @VisualVincent I already split the file up into packets. I'm testing out how much it can take, and right now it sends 1,000,000 bytes in a few seconds and was wondering if I could speed that up by increasing the packet size.

Comment: Don't know for sure, but I can measure it. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: After testing it on my local computer it seems there are not much of a change. I'm going to try over different networks...

Comment: I can confirm that changing `Send/ReceiveBufferSize` doesn't not do much difference. After testing there seemed to be no notable difference in the send/receive speed - _Information from the chat between me and Question Asker_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCP protocol does not know what a `TcpClient` is. This is a .NET concept. TCP does not reference .NET concepts at all. For that reason no objects will be sent across the wire.

The only thing that is sent is the bytes you explicitly write.

Each side has it's own isolated objects. Both sides use their own `TcpClient` object which acts like a handle to the TCP connection.

```
client.GetStream.Close()
client.Close()
```

This is not the proper shutdown sequence. The first line is redundant to the second and incomplete. Close should never be called. The best way to do it is to wrap the client in `using`. The second best way is to call `Dispose` on the client. The `Close` methods in the BCL are historic accidents and should be ignored. They do the same thing that Dispose does in all cases that I ever looked at.

Don't touch the buffer sizes. They control how much memory the kernel uses to buffer data on your end of the connection. The kernel is capable of managing this by itself.

Also don't look at the buffer sizes in your code. They are meaningless. Also don't use the `DataAvailable` property because if it returns `false/0` this does not mean that no data can be read.

The `Connected` property is not necessarily synchronized on both sides. If the network goes down there can be no synchronization. Never look at the `Connected` property. If it says `true` the next nanosecond it could be `false`. So it's not possible to make decisions based on that property. You do not need to test anything. Just Read/Write and handle the exceptions by aborting.

Regarding packets, you are not sending packets when you `Write`. TCP has a boundaryless stream of bytes. The kernel packetizes your data internally. You do not need to split data into specific sizes. Just use a fairly big buffer size such as 8K (or more on fast networks). The write size is only about saving CPU time by being less chatty (assuming nagling is enabled).

Comment: When you say it's best to use `using`, that's not possible if everything isn't contained in one sub... what should I do then? Just call `Dispose`?

Comment: Yes, call Dispose. Or, rearrange the code so that it's all one sub. You can also do this pattern: `void HandleConn(TcpClient client) { using (client) ... }`. `using` does not require `new`.

Comment: Yeah - the problem is that I've made a wrapper class for it with separate functions for sending / receiving

Comment: You could make the wrapper IDisposable and use using for the wrapper.

Comment: Im not sure... each time the client disconnects and then reconnects, I initialize a new instance of `TcpClient` in the wrapper. Could you explain what you meant by the `DataAvailable` property not being reliable? When does that occur?

Comment: Let's say DA == 0. Then, one nanosecond later a byte arrives but you already concluded there was no data. You can't decide based an DA.

Comment: I see what you mean. But DA determines availability at the time of reading which is fine for me since I'm looping the receive anyway. (I include the length of data at the start of each packet, so receive will loop until it gets all data if any).

Comment: And what do you do if DA == 0?

Comment: It returns "" which means no data read. I only check DA at the start of a receive operation.

Comment: And then? Do you give up on reading forever although new data might come a split second later?

Comment: Why do you test DA then? Sounds like you have a busy loop burning CPU.

Comment: Haha - you've got me. I haven't started using `Async` yet in my app, and I use the blocking methods to read/write.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Just don't ever test anything with sockets. Just do and expect failure. Sync APIs are still totally fine.

Comment: Btw if I don't have a busy loop, then what else can I have? Surely it has to check periodically either way.

Comment: Ah - I see. I meant that it reads every timer tick, by 'loop', not an actual while loop.

Comment: Here's a good pattern: `while (true) { var read = stream.Read(...); if (read == 0) break; ProcessData(...); }`. This is all that is needed. Use `StreamReader` and `BinaryReader` to increase convenience further but use the same pattern.

Comment: I tried changing the code just now, and the compiler tells me I can't call `Dispose` on the `TcpClient` because `Dispose` is protected?

Comment: Hm no TcpClient is IDisposable. This is some other issue. Maybe the variable is not of type TcpClient. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823304(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I see why — I'm still using 2010 and haven't upgraded yet. Nevermind then.